# Select max amount spent in single order

Tags: r, sqldf

I am very new to R and sqldf and can't seem to solve a basic problem. I have a file with transactions where each row represents a product purchased.

The file looks like this:

```
customer_id,order_number,order_date, amount, product_name
1, 202, 21/04/2015, 58, "xlfd"
1, 275, 16//08/2015, 74, "ghb"
1, 275, 16//08/2015, 36, "fjk"
2, 987, 12/03/2015, 27, "xlgm"
3, 376, 16/05/2015, 98, "fgt"
3, 368, 30/07/2015, 46, "ade"
```

I need to find the maximum amount spent in a single transaction (same `order_number`) by each `customer_id`. For example in case of `customer_id "1"` it would be `(74+36)=110`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the dataframe is named `orders`, following will do the job:

```
sqldf("select customer_id, order_number, sum(amount) 
       from orders 
       group by customer_id, order_number")
```

**Update:** using nested query the following will give the desired output:

```
sqldf("select customer_id, max(total) 
       from (select customer_id, order_number, sum(amount) as total 
             from orders 
             group by customer_id, order_number) 
       group by customer_id")
```

Output:

```
    customer_id max(total)
1           1        110
2           2         27
3           3         98
```

Comment: This returns total amount spent per user per purchase, while required output seems just the maximum amount in a single purchase out of all purchases for a user. Maybe take this output and extract `customer_id, max(sum(amount))` with `group by customer_id` ?

Comment: @Elena Berrone, please accept the answer, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

In case `sqldf` is not a strict requirement.

Considering your input as `dft` , you can try:

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)
dft %>% 
    group_by(customer_id, order_number) %>% 
    summarise(amt = sum(amount)) %>% 
    group_by(customer_id) %>% 
    summarise(max_amt = max(amt))
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: customer_id [3]

  customer_id max_amt
        <int>   <int>
1           1     110
2           2      27
3           3      98
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'customer_id', 'order_number', we get the `sum` of 'amount', do a second group by with 'customer_id' and get the `max` of 'Sumamount'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Sumamount = sum(amount)) , .(customer_id, order_number)
        ][,.(MaxAmount = max(Sumamount)) , customer_id]
#   customer_id MaxAmount
#1:           1       110
#2:           2        27
#3:           3        98
```

---

Or making it more compact, after grouping by 'customer_id', we `split` the 'amount' by 'order_number', loop through the `list`, get the `sum`, find the `max` to get the 'MaxAmount'

```
setDT(df1)[, .(MaxAmount = max(unlist(lapply(split(amount,
                      order_number), sum)))), customer_id]
#   customer_id MaxAmount
#1:           1       110
#2:           2        27
#3:           3        98
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(amount~customer_id, aggregate(amount~customer_id+order_number, 
                         df1, sum), FUN = max)
```